# HTTP Error 404: Not Found Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following data frame that I want to plot in FacetGrid using Seaborn library.

```
   projectId  sentDate   correspondenceId   Year Month
0      10417  2001-09-25             8710   2001     9
1      10417  2001-10-01             9173   2001    10
2      10417  2001-10-05             9676   2001    10
3      10417  2001-10-24            11487   2001    10
4      10417  2001-10-29            11872   2001    10
```

I am using the following code to plot it

```
data_plot = sns.load_dataset("new_df")
f = sns.FacetGrid(data_plot, col="Year", col_wrap=4, size=1.5)
f = f.map(plt.plot, "Month", "correspondenceId.count()", marker=".")
```

But I am getting an error

```
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

My library is up to date. I am new to programming so I still do a lot of trial and error while coding to get the correct output. 
Any ideas how to resolve this issue?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load_dataset functionality of seaborn looks online for it's datasets.

From the docstring

> Help on function load_dataset in module seaborn.utils:
>
> load_dataset(name, cache=True, data_home=None, **kws)
>       Load a dataset from the online repository (requires internet).
>
> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> name : str
>     Name of the dataset (`name`.csv on
>     https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data).  You can obtain list of
>     available datasets using :func:`get_dataset_names`
> cache : boolean, optional
>     If True, then cache data locally and use the cache on subsequent calls
> data_home : string, optional
>     The directory in which to cache data. By default, uses ~/seaborn-data/
> kws : dict, optional
>     Passed to pandas.read_csv
> ```

Since in the defined online repository there is no new_df file it returns a 404 error.

You can just pass your dataframe to seaborn functions (if it is already defined in your code).

So if you df is called `new_df`.

```
f = sns.FacetGrid(new_df, col="Year", col_wrap=4, size=1.5)
```

Should use your dataframe.